QZ Tray Not Connecting to Local Client Printers in Production
I hope you're doing well. I want to connect my web service or application from production to the local client printer using QZ Tray. Do you know if this is possible? It works great in the local environment, but when I deploy it to production and try to connect from a local PC, it doesn’t allow me to do so and shows the following error:
index-D0vmELM7.js:94 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8182/' failed: Uncaught (in promise) Error: No open connection with QZ Tray.

Could someone please help me or provide guidance on how to configure QZ Tray? Here is my code:
`"qz-tray": "^2.2.4",`

 try {
        // Generar el PDF a partir del HTML
        const pdfBlob = await GeneratePrintTicketPdfFromHtml(params);

        const base64Pdf = await convertBlobToBase64Async(pdfBlob, pdfBlob.type);

        // Verificar si estás en entorno de producción o desarrollo
        const isProduction = import.meta.env.PROD;

        const options: ConnectOptions = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: {
                secure: [8182],
                insecure: [8182],
            },
            usingSecure: isProduction,
            keepAlive: 60, // Tiempo de vida de la conexión en segundos
            retries: 3, // Número de intentos de reconexión
            delay: 5 // Segundos de espera entre intentos
        };

        await qz.websocket.connect(options);

        // Obtener la impresora predeterminada del sistema
        const printers = await qz.printers.find(); // Devuelve la impresora por defecto

        if (printers.length === 0) {
            showErrorToast('Error', 'No se encontró ninguna impresora instalada');
            return;
        }

        // Configurar la impresora predeterminada y opciones de impresión
        const config = qz.configs.create(printers[0]); // Usa la primera impresora, que debería ser la predeterminada

        // Convertir el blob a un archivo imprimible
        const data: PrintData[] = [{
            type: 'pixel',
            format: 'pdf',
            flavor: 'base64',
            data: base64Pdf, // Convertimos el Blob a base64
        }];

        // Enviar el trabajo de impresión a QZ Tray
        await qz.print(config, data);

        // Mostrar un mensaje de éxito si se imprime correctamente
        showSuccessToast('Éxito', 'El ticket se ha impreso correctamente');

        // Desconectar de QZ Tray después de imprimir
        await qz.websocket.disconnect();

    } catch (err) {
        handleError(err);
    }
};

I tried to connect my web application from production to the customer's local printer using QZ Tray. I expected the connection to work smoothly, just like in my local environment. However, I received an error saying “No connection open with QZ Tray”, which prevented the connection from being established.

secure: [8182], insecure: [8182].  QZ Tray will never start a wss:// (secure websocket connection) on 8182.  Why did you change secure:  from the default value of 8181, 8282, 8383, 8484?  Can you please change this to 8181?  insecure:  can be left at 8182.
